# Hierarchical menu tree including all subitems on any level

Tags: php, mysql, menu, tree, hierarchical

I am thinking of what the best way is to store a given menu tree for a shop-like system. That includes a menu tree with multiple sub-levels and items that are assigned to those levels.

Special requirements:
 - Each level needs to include *all* items of the sub- and sub-n-levels
 - Each item (might!) be assigned to multiple levels

Short example:

```
[Category A]
  [Category A-A]
    - Product: Apple
    [Category A-A-A]
      - Product: Pear
[Category B]
  - Product: Salad
  - Product: Apple
```

Following ouputs:
- Display root: The tree + all products shall be shown (1x Apple !, Pear and Salad)
- Display Category A-A: The tree + Apple and Pear shall be shown
- Display Category A-A-A: The tree + only Pear shall be shown

Any suggestions or hints to achieve that with help of PHP and MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

(for a first reading)

Answer (score 0):

You should javascript tree library for this which can be generated from PHP code.
See the following link, you can choose anyone.

http://www.queness.com/post/1138/10-javascriptcss-treeview-and-sitemap-plugins-and-tutorials